# Do I get the continent troops on every turn I have conquered the continent?

Tags: risk

If I have conquered the entire continent do I get those bonus continent troops on each turn I play or just one turn after I have conquered it?

Answer (score 3):

You receive bonus troops for a continent each time you *begin your turn* in control of every district/nation on that continent, *for as long as that remains true*.  That is, if you lose control of any district on the continent, you will not collect the bonus troops at the start of your next turn.

from [Rules of Risk](https://www.ultraboardgames.com/risk/game-rules.php)

> #### Continents
>
> In addition, at the beginning of your turn, you will receive armies for each continent you control. (To control a continent, you must occupy all its territories at the start of your turn).

Comment: A quote or link to the relevant ruling would be great :)